# Requests não baixa arquivos > que 4MB

Tags: python, libcurl

Estou utilizando o requests no python, e não consigo baixar arquivos maiores que 4mb (talvez um pouco menores também).
Eu estou fazendo download de alguns PDF, e consigo fazer o download de arquivo pequenos normalmente, mas quando utilizo um arquivo um pouco maior, ele só salva o nome e deixa como um arquivo em branco. Utilizei o CURL e ele baixou normalmente, mas quando utilizo o CURL dentro do python invés do request, ele também não realiza o download.

```
def download_file(url,name):
#response = requests.get(url, stream=True, allow_redirects=True)
#pdf_url = response.url
#handle = open(name+".pdf", "wb")
#for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=512):
#    if chunk:  
#        handle.write(chunk)

os.system('curl "{}" -o "{}".pdf'.format(url,name))
```

Existe algum limitador sobre o tamanho do arquivo que estou criando? Procurei sobre e não achei nada sobre....

Comment: Aparece alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: Será que não esta sendo limitado pelo servidor? Tem servidor que tenta bloquear a ação de bots e crawlers.